# Redshift NVL() numeric giving wrong answer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, nvl

I have the following query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table1 ACTUAL, table1 ANTERIOR
ACTUAL.fecha=to_date(20180102,'YYYYMMDD') AND ANTERIOR.fecha=to_date(20180101,'YYYYMMDD')
WHERE ACTUAL.CONTRATO=ANTERIOR.CONTRATO 
AND ACTUAL.SECCION=ANTERIOR.SECCION
AND (
       ACTUAL.CD_EMPR_COM<>ANT.CD_EMPR_COM
       OR NVL(ACTUAL.FH_BAJA_CRTO,'9999-01-01')<>NVL(ANTERIOR.FH_BAJA_CRTO,'9999-01-01')


OR NVL(ACTUAL.POWER,0)<>NVL(ANTERIOR.POWER_1,0)

--ERROR, THE NUMBER RESULTANT NOT IS CORRECT

-OR NVL(ACTUAL.POWER,-9)<>NVL(ANTERIOR.POWER,-9)
)
```

If I apply to the filter `NVL (ACTUAL.POWER, 0)` the result is correct, but if I apply the filter `NVL (ACTUAL.POWER, 1)` or `NVL (ACTUAL.POWER, -9)` the result of the query is not correct.

Comment: Can you possibly provide a simplified query to prove your situation, so that we can try to reproduce the problem? For example, just a simple `NVL(1234,-9)`.

Comment: You need to explain _how_ the result is not correct, otherwise there is not enough information to suggest an answer, ideally with an example as John suggests.